# removing null chars from android string

Tags: java, android, string

In my android project, i want to read a data structure from file.  A field suppose 'name', which has maximum of 32 chars.  Most of the time 'name' field contains less than maximum limit.  Some unwanted chars (i think 'null') is filled with data. i used 'trim' method to remove, but nothing happened.  I need only valid data for processing, how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: store your data as xml or json and use android parsers to read it.

Comment: data is from a hardware system, their format is raw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use regular expression to replace non-printable characters.

```
String string=line.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the ascii value of the character is greater than 0 to check whether the character is null

**How to remove null from android String**

```
String str = "abc def";
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            byte[] byteArray = str.getBytes();
            for(byte bytedata:byteArray){
                if(bytedata>0){
                    sb.append((char)bytedata);
                }
            }
            str = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("..."+str);
```

Comment: use toCharArray rather than getBytes. On any platform using UTF-8 as default encoding with any characters > 127 your solution will append incorrect values.

Answer (score 0):

If the char 0 is appended at the end of the String, just find its first index in the String, and substring up to this index:

```
int nullCharIndex = s.indexOf((char) 0);
if (nullCharIndex >= 0) {
    s = s.substring(0, nullCharIndex);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have a name field that is completly null just check, whether the string == null.

If you want to parse one string, which contains for example spaces jsut use:

```
String string = "a b c d";
string.replaceAll(" ","");
```

This can be used for every other char. Be aware that you have to use RegEx for that.

Comment: Your example demonstrate what might be the problem in his code. string is immutable, so you should assign the result of replaceAll to some String.